# Drawing textures with transparency

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have a png textrure with tranparency, I load it this way using wxwidgets 
[wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxImage_to_load_textures_for_OpenGL](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxImage_to_load_textures_for_OpenGL)

I am trying to draw it on another texture, but i get black color where it should be transparent,

```
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
   glEnable (GL_BLEND);

   glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    showflags = true;
    if (showflags)
    {
    //render flags
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    for(int i=0;i<DrawnFlagsNum;i++)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(DrawnFlags[i].x,DrawnFlags[i].y,0);
        switch(DrawnFlags[i].t)
        {
        case blue: blueflag->render();break;
        case yellow: yellowflag->render();break;
        case green: greenflag->render();break;
        }
        glPopMatrix();
    }
 glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    if (VideoTexture != 0)
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glPushMatrix();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VideoTexture);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(Width, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(Width, Height);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, Height);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }



    //renderFirstFrame();
    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers();
```

flags are the top textures;

Comment: had you tried to draw non-textured quad of some color first (not covering whole screen)? just to test you have right camera vs object matrix settings so you debugging the right thing. You use resolution as quad vertex coordinates if you have not set projection and modelview accordingly ... than maybe you have just extremly enlarged quad. also instead glTexCoord2i would be better glTexCoord2f

Comment: I can draw flags outside of big texture. I use 2D Viewport.